# Using Frames and Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe

Hi I am making a Java program with multiple threads where each thread prints a sequence of charecters in a Jframe. How can I make sure that all threads write the charecters in the same frame ?

Comment: Post your code and we will try to guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Create the `JFrame` before you create the threads. Pass the `JFrame` to all the threads as you create them. Have the threads then add the characters.

Note that you should use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to do the actual adding of characters safely from each processing thread because most Swing methods can only be safely called from Swing's Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).